How to run a python file from another file
I am trying to do some multiple files programming and I am not sure how to run my file from another file.
 def execute_python_file(self):
    try:
        os.system('python HabitTracker.py')
    except FileNotFoundError:
         print(f"Error: The file '{HabitTracker}' does not exist.")

I found this code off the internet. It starts a subprocess, but it reruns the current python file.

Is HabitTracker.py the python file you want to execute?

What do you mean by "run"? Have you considered importing? And what do you mean by "reruns the current python file"? Are you saying HabitTracker.py is the current file? Please provide more details - ideally a [mre]. For more tips, see How to ask a good question.

What exactly do you want to achieve after running another python file ? Can you provide more context?

Why not subprocess or import to do this?

This code
 def execute_python_file(self):
    try:
        os.system('python HabitTracker.py')
    except FileNotFoundError:
         print(f"Error: The file '{HabitTracker}' does not exist.")

would not do what you might think, as os.system would not raise FileNotFoundError even if HabitTracker.py does not exists. Even if it did, then print would use value of HabitTracker variable, whilst os.system always attempts to use HabitTracker.py file without caring about value of HabitTracker variable. Beyond that said code assumes that python command is available and it is of correct version, for example some systems still furnish python version 2 under python. Due to that I discourage to use shown code as paragon.

trying to do some multiple files programming

Then you should probably create files with functions, then import them and use as you wish.

    import subprocess

    def execute_python_file(file_name):
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(['python', file_name], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to execute '{file_name}'.\n{e}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: The file '{file_name}' does not exist.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

    # Example usage
    execute_python_file('HabitTracker.py')`

I would try it like this ^
You might still need to use the full path to the interpreter.
